# How to get the recorded voice in the form of a file recorded using ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH android

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I'm using RecognizerIntent to record user voice. I'm using following code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                matches));
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Here I'm getting the recorded speech as string. I want to obtain the recorded voice file to store it on sdcard.

How should I get it?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: I need to do this too. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Check this http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-android-sensor/index.html Go to 'Media Recorder' tutorial, example code is also provided..

Comment: Thanks neha, but that does not help me. I want to use RecognizerIntent to get the speech to text translation string AND be able to access the audio that the user spoke. I want the text string AND the audio file. Make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this work using tutorial at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-android-sensor/index.html.